# Meaning of "watch your six"

Tags: meaning, idioms, american-english

What does "watch your six" mean?

Does it mean "watch your back", like in a dangerous area?

Comment: You can see a pretty good definition by scrolling down on [this page](http://www.tailhook.org/AVSLANG.htm). [This one](http://books.google.com/books?id=wjhlH5-CIo8C&pg=PA118&lpg=PA118&dq=%22Check+six%22&source=bl&ots=vqinHgohAs&sig=BCQaQdGtGle3L0GqAmxhP589Efw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=HeevUaDeH4qdrAHAxYGYCw&ved=0CFEQ6AEwBTge#v=onepage&q=%22Check%20six%22&f=false) is interesting, too.

Comment: i looked "six" up and it also means "equivalent to the product of two and three; one more than five, or four less than ten; as in the sentence: "she's lived here six months" ... easy peasy

Comment: One can find a sample usage of the collocation in the [Gemini Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemini_Man_(film)) movie. If to be particularly accurate the 18:00 - 18:10 minute of the movie.

Answer (score 22):

Your intuitions are correct; the phrase '*watch your six*' does indeed mean '*watch your back*'.

It refers to the 6 position on the face of a clock. If you were standing in the center of a clock face, facing the 12 position, the 6 position would be immediately behind you. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_position):

> Using this analogy, *12 o'clock means ahead or above, 3 o'clock means to the right, 6 o'clock means behind or below, and 9 o'clock means to the left*. The other eight hours refer to directions that are not directly in line with the four major directions.

Comment: For further information, see [Top Gun (1986)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_Gun).

Comment: Similarly "Check six". http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_does_check_six_mean

Answer (score 4):

This phrase is often used by combat fighter pilots to refer to keeping an eye out for enemy attacks coming from behind.